# How to make an enumeration like this?

Tags: text-formatting, microsoft-word-2013

I want to make a *decent* enumeration (not typing the numbers and letters myself) as follows:

> 1. a. Some text 
>      b. Some text
> 2. Some text
> 3. a. Some text

Is this possible in Word 2013? I repeat: I want to use "real" enumerations that change according to content that has been inserted before or after the element. I do not want to write the enumerations myself.

Comment: You've made it clear what you want from us, but what have you researched or tried on yourself?

Comment: @CharlieRB I searched the net (even though I didn't really know which keywords to use) and looked all over the functions in Word. Nothing more I can do I guess.

Comment: Multilevel lists don't work that way, so I doubt you will be able to get Word to put the enumeration on the same line automatically. I couldn't find anything to get it to do as you ask.

Comment: @CharlieRB See my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PamCaswell [helped me out](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/display-sub-item-of-enumeration-next-to-parent/1539eaac-24a2-4e75-ba00-3be9e8928b42) on the official Microsoft forums.
Important links:

- [ListNUM fields](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-listnum-field-HP005189547.aspx)
- [How to use the ListNUM field](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162895/en-us)

I'll write down in short how you do this:

1. Press ctrl + F9. Curly brackets should appear
2. In these curly brackets, type the following: LISTNUM \l 2
3. Press alt + F9 to toggle between the normal view and the field view

So, after inserting the field code, you'll have something like this.

[image: Before]

If you hen press alt + F9, you'll have this:
[image: After]

Good luck.

Comment: How does this do what you are asking above?

Comment: @CharlieRB See my edit.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, but I don't understand how you are getting it to do the `(3)` or `(2)`, etc. So you still have to do the number manually?

Comment: No, the first enumeration ((1), (2) and so on) is like you would normally make an ordered list.